# Help me convert my gaming headset plugs (mic & stereo sound) to a single 2.5mm monaural plug

Tags: audio, adapter

I have a seldom used piece of computer hardware I'd like to connect a gaming headset to. The headset has two 3.5mm plugs (mic and sound) like this: 
[image]

The jack I need to plug into is a 2.5mm monaural (don't ask me why--I know it sounds goofy but it's for someone else who's very picky). I googled a few different ways but I could only find splitters [such as this](http://www.lightinthebox.com/15CM-3-5mm-Plug-to-3-5mm-Double-Jacks--SZM525-_p57255.html?pos=ultimately_buy_1) for going from 2 x 3.5mm to 1 3.5mm. If I could find one that could combine it properly to 1 3.5mm, I could then find a 3.5mm to 2.5mm adapter. I know I could probably vivisect and work something out, but I need it to be very clean. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [Here:](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00331S5FK)

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I have completely revised my answer based on the comment discussions.

I can't find an off-the shelf lead for this so it may be a soldering job.

- The L-R headphone wires can be joined
  together to give a mono headset - H
  in diagram below.
- The mic may or may
  not be stereo, but only one wire
  should be used - M1 OR M2 in diagram
  below.

You will need to work out which of A or B on the 2.5mm TRS plug connects to the headset output and mic input on your kit, then wire H and Mn to them accordingly. The screen/ground wires from the sockets are joined together and wired to the ground connector (sleeve) on the 2.5mm plug.

To make this up, I'd buy a 3.5mm stereo socket to socket lead and a 2.5mm stereo jack (TRS) plug. Cut the lead in half. The two wires in the lead will probably be a red/white or red/black pair + screen

Hope this makes sense. Have fun!

[image: Wiring diagram]

Comment: @Linker3000: No, I need both listening and mic. 3 contact 2.5mm. Mic and mono sound. Sortof like cell phone headsets: http://www.phonescoop.com/glossary/term.php?gid=360

Comment: @Flotsam N. Jetsam  Do you need listening and mic at the same time?

Comment: OK, the confusing bit was mentioning 2.5mm 'monoaural' - Let's see what I can dig up...

Comment: @AdrejaKo: Yes Indeed.

Comment: Tons of Googling later and I reckon you will be doing some soldering! Are you up to that?

Comment: @Linker3000: Argh. I need to avoid that actually. Thanks for trying.

Comment: No probs - revised answer above with diagram goodness.

Comment: No probs - stuck in bed with flu so it's good to do something useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make it manually. 
You`ll need to cut off those 2 plugs & then solder wires to the 2.5mm jack.

Comment: Not really helpful - no wiring info provided.

Comment: I mentioned not wanting to cut in the question.